# Does anyone know why my script for a basic smart assistant isn't taking or completing my commands i tell it?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

This is my script for a basic smart assistant i've been working on for a beginner project.

When i run it, all that prints is "exit code (0)" none of my other commands show.

It doesn't even print "listening" or activates the microphone.
i'm guessing this is because i have the order of the script wrong or im missing some code?

```
import datetime  # clock
import pyjokes  # jokes
import pyttsx3  # text to speech
import speech_recognition as sr
import wikipedia  # wikipedia



# Initialize the recognizer 
listener = sr.Recognizer() 
  
# Function to convert text to
# speech
def talk(text):
      
    # Initialize the engine
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
    engine.setProperty('rate', 125)
    # speech volume
    volume = engine.getProperty('volume')  # getting to know current volume level (min=0 and max=1)      #printing current volume level
    engine.setProperty('volume', 1.0)  # setting up volume level  between 0 and 1
    # voice
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')  # getting details of current voice
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)  # changing index, changes voices. 1 for female
    engine.say(text) 
    engine.runAndWait()
      
def run_charlie(command):
    
    if (command=='hi'):
        print("hello")

    elif (command=='time'):
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
        talk('Current time is ' + time)

    elif (command=='who is'):
        person = command.replace('who is', '')
        info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1)
        print(info)
        talk(info)

    elif (command=='how are you'):
        talk('I am good, how are you?')
        
    elif (command=='joke'):
        talk(pyjokes.get_joke())

    else:
        talk('Please say the command again.')
# Loop infinitely for user to
# speak
  
while(1):    
      
    try:
          
        with sr.Microphone() as source2:
            print('listening...')
            listener.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source2, duration=0.2)
            audio2 =  listener.listen(source2)
            MyText =  listener.recognize_google(audio2)
            MyText = MyText.lower()
            #print("Did you say "+MyText)
            talk(MyText)
            run_charlie(MyText)
            if (MyText == 'charlie'):
                MyText = MyText.replace('charlie', '')
                print(MyText)


    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))
          
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("unknown error occurred")
```

Comment: The script actually works on my machine so I'm unable to reproduce the issue. Can you try making a minimal example that produces the error to narrow down where it is coming from. For example, try removing `pyjoke` and `wikipedia` from your example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i tried to find where the error is, but whenever i removed something it still ran with "exit code (0)". Is there a command that i could have accidentally added that returns "exit code (0)" even when there is faults in the script? And somehow bypasses the errors?

Comment: This works perfectly fine on my computer.
Can you give us more details? modules and python versions? Operating system? IDE? Have you tried running it in multiple IDE to check? Have you tried to debug it? line after line? see exactly where the program terminates and why, and then you could start figuring out why.

Comment: What faults/errors are you referring to?